# How to fix the absolute position issue?

Tags: html, css

I have a question regarding the absolute position div.

I have something like

```
<div id='body-container'>
    <div id='content-wrapper'>
        contents....
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to make my `body-wrapper` with absolute position because of other issues.

my css

```
#body-container{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

I have encounter a problem. Inside my `content-wrapper`, I have dynamic contents that will be added inside. It will create a unwanted scrollbar and the div become scrollable in that div. Is there anyway to kill the scrolling behavior? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `height` property from your `#body-container`, and it will fit the content's height. No scrollbar.

http://jsfiddle.net/QeFe5/

**EDIT**

If you need the wrapper to be full height, then don't forget to set the `top: 0` property, so the body won't create a scroll:

```
#body-container{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: silver;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/QeFe5/1/

Comment: Thanks, but I need to have my body extend all the way to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

This might work...

```
    #body-container{
        position: relative;
    }
    #content-wrapper{
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 100px; /* Need to put an exact height */
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Comment: I do need to have my content-wrapper 100% height so it can be extend to the bottom of the page. Putting 100% just make the content-wrapper disappear :(

Answer (score 0):

If you need the content-wrapper to extend the full page you can use top and bottom with absolute positioning and make sure that your body-container (and it's enclosing containers) have height 100%.

```
#body-container{
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
#content-wrapper{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom:0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```